# Patch before the user navigates

Tags: angular, http

Is there a way to call a PATCH call when the user navigates out to another component with out a save button?

Right now I have a spreadsheet view that I would like to save when the user leaves the page.

Comment: maybe you should take a look at lifecycle hooks. ngOnDestroy() should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only wanting to catch the user leaving the page for another page on your app the OnDestroy lifecycle hook is the way to go. Be aware that this will not catch instances where the user leaves your site or closes the browser.

If you want to catch those you will need to use the browser beforeunload handler. For full coverage you should use both.

Something like the following should work.

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload')
public saveOnExit() {
    ..call save method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent a user from leaving (unless they save the data) you may use build-in Router [CanDeactivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate) guard. It is based on router navigation.

It won't catch the cases where the user is about to leave the tab or close the browser, in that case implementing logic that listens to `window:beforeunload` event is a good solution.

Combination of these should be fine for all edge cases.

---

I recommend reading this blog post which sums up topic nicely

[How to keep the user from losing data in Angular](https://medium.com/better-programming/angular-how-keep-user-from-lost-his-data-by-accidentally-leaving-the-page-before-submit-4eeb74420f0d)